# Tabulator moveable rows -- how to select / move multiple items at one time

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Using Tabulator 4.7, I have implemented an app that has moving items between tables, much like this example:

http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7?#movable-between-tables

However, I can't figure out how to select and move multiple items at one time. I'm not sure if it is even possible, since when I use something like

```
            selectable:5,
```

along with

```
            movableRows:true,
            movableRowsConnectedTables:otherTableIDs,
            movableRowsReceiver: "add",
            movableRowsSender: "delete",
```

it doesn't change the behavior. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of version 4.7, You cannot move multiple rows at a time with Tabulator.

The [Movable Rows](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/move#rows) functionality only allows for one row to be moved at a time.

This functionality is on the development roadmap for after the 5.0 release

Comment: Thanks for that information. I know roadmaps are always changing, but do you have a general target for when 5.0 is due to be out?

Answer (score 1):

For moving multiple rows within a single table, this code will do the trick.

The rowMoving event to used to identify rows that are selected.

```
 rowMoving = (row) => {
    this.rowsToMove = [];
    let rows = this.tableInst.getRows();
    for (let row of rows) {
      let rowData = _.cloneDeep(row.getData());
      if (row.isSelected()) {
        this.rowsToMove.push(rowData);
      }
    }
  };
```

The rowMoved event is used to insert the rowsToMove into the dragged-to location in the table.

```
  rowMoved = (row) => {
    let rowsToMove = this.rowsToMove;
    let rowsOrg = this.tableInst.getData();
    let rowsNext = [];
    let rowsHaveBeenMoved = false;
    for (let row of rowsOrg) {
      if (this.isRowsToMove(rowsToMove, row)) {
        if (!rowsHaveBeenMoved) {
          for (let r of rowsToMove) {
            rowsNext.push(r);
          }
          rowsHaveBeenMoved = true;
        }
      } else {
        rowsNext.push(row);
      }
    }
    this.tableInst.replaceData(rowsNext);
  };
```

This helper function is used to see if a row matches any of the rowsToMove.

```
  isRowsToMove = (rows, row) => {
    let match = false;
    for (let r of rows) {
      if (_.isEqual(r, row)) {
        match = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return match;
  };
```